# Avoid that EditText consumes click event

Tags: android, onclick, android-edittext

Normally it's enough to set `focusable`, `focusableInTouch` + `clickable` to false. But here it does not work.

I want the parent `LinearLayout` to consume clicks on the `EditText` as well but it does not work...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="@null" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etText"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:ems="4"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried `editable=false` and `inputType=none` but it does not work. Why not? The `EditText` consumes the click and does not hand it on to it's parent.

**EDIT**

I'm setting an `onClickListener` to  the `LinearLayout` and it does not work if I directly press the `EditText`...

Comment: have you tried `android:clickable="true"` on your linear layout?

Comment: yes, I'm setting an `onClickListener` to it... it works as long as I don't press the `EditText`...

Answer (score 41):

Late, but maybe somebody else needs this info.
After setting focusable, focusableInTouch + clickable to false, add this in your java code:

```java
editText.setMovementMethod(null);
editText.setKeyListener(null);
```

Don't forget to save those values to restore them later:

```java
mMovementMethod = mEditText.getMovementMethod();
mKeyListener = mEditText.getKeyListener();
```

Comment: the edittext wouldn't work for me after restoring the listeners until i set `focusableInTouchMode` to true

Answer (score 0):

You should use ViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent)

> This method  is to intercept all touch screen motion events

Comment: I prefer using a `TextView` and style it like an `EditText` to this... Still, I'm interested why above solution works everywhere but with an `EditText`...