# How to make EditText's parent clickable?

Tags: android, android-edittext, xamarin.android

Suppose I have this pink box:

[image: pinku bokkusu]

It consists of `LinearLayout` with its children: `TextView` as field name and an `EditText`. `EditText` is intentionally disabled. What I want is that, user can click wherever user wants on that pink box. By the way, please just ignore any UI/UX things that you found weird.

I've tried, but user can't tap the area that `EditText` occupies. User have to tap in `TextView` or blank area on pink box so that the apps got the 'click'. But if user taps on `EditText`'s area, nothing will happen.

I've tried playing with some things in xml's properties, such as set `LinearLayout`'s `clickable` to `true`, and all children or just `EditText`'s properties of `clickable`, `focusable`, and `focusableInTouchMode` to `false`, all to no avail. `EditText` area still cannot be clicked.

Any idea? Can't it be reached just through xml? Should it be done programmatically just to turn bypass `EditText`'s click?

Comment: your description is very confusing.

Comment: post the layout code of edittext

Comment: You can try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33303222/4964019 It's help for me.

Comment: Try This (Using a Custom Layout and override "onInterceptTouchEvent" Inside it...) https://stackoverflow.com/a/53384478/2077850

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add onTouch  Listener instead of click Listener.

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the parent layout (LinearLayout, whatever) and loop through the views if you dont want to bind them all. If you use databinding its easier. Anyway, here is a solution (a small piece of code is **required**!).

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="out of focus"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearTest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test for clicking"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="another clicking test"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="focus edittext when clicking linearlayout or other elements inside"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.linear_focus_test);

        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTest);

        LinearLayout linearTest = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearTest);
            for (int i = 0; i < linearTest.getChildCount(); i++)

            View v = linearTest.getChildAt(i);
            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    editText.requestFocus();
                }
            });
        }
}
```

If you dont like boilerplate you may also use lambda (use 1.8 features)

```
for (int i = 0; i < linearTest.getChildCount(); i++)
            linearTest.getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(v1 -> editText.requestFocus());
```

If you use at least API 24 you can even make it shorter:

```
IntStream.range(0, linearTest.getChildCount()).forEach(i -> linearTest.getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(v1 -> editText.requestFocus()));
```