# Android: How to make Layout clickable when EditText is a child

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a Relative Layout with an EditText and an ImageView inside it. 
Under certain circumstances, I would like to make the whole layout clickable and not any of its children.

I added an OnClickListener on the layout. And I tried the following with the children:
1. setEnabled(false)
2. setClickable(false)

This works for the ImageView but even after the above changes, when I click on the area near the EditText, the keyboard comes up and I can see the cursor in the edit text. 
Instead of that, I am hoping that all click/touch events go to the layout.

Could some one help?
Thanks

Comment: Please, let me know if you could make it work. Cheers.

Comment: yes worked. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yon create a CustomLayout class and override the `onInterceptTouchEvent` method. If that method returns `true`, the layout's childrens will not receive the touch event. You can create a member variable and a public setter to change the returning value.

**CustomLayout class**

```
public class CustomLayout extends LinearLayout {

    //If set to false, the children are clickable. If set to true, they are not.
    private boolean mDisableChildrenTouchEvents;

    public CustomLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mDisableChildrenTouchEvents = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return mDisableChildrenTouchEvents;
    }

    public void setDisableChildrenTouchEvents(boolean flag) {
        mDisableChildrenTouchEvents = flag;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CustomLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.mylayout);

        //Disable touch events in Children
        layout.setDisableChildrenTouchEvents(true);

        layout.setOnClickListener(v -> System.out.println("Layout clicked"));
    }
}
```

**XML Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<com.example.dglozano.myapplication.CustomLayout
    android:id="@+id/mylayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/outline"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</com.example.dglozano.myapplication.CustomLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Nice...It was clever solution.